# Best practice: What is the best way to store exception/error or informational messages in C#.net for internationalization?

Tags: c#, .net, database, resources

When throwing custom exceptions or issuing messages to the end user, one could use hard-coded the strings (including string constants), use resource-only assemblies or get strings from a table in a database.

I would like my application to be able to switch to a different language easily without having to recompile.  While storing the string resources in a assembly or database would achieve this purpose, it adds to the complexity of program logic which in turn adds to the cost of the product.

My question is: what is the best way to go with the objective in mind without ignoring the cost that comes with each option?  If you have a practice that is better than what's been listed, I'd love to hear it.

Technologies:
OS: Windows family
Platform: .NET Frame 2 and up
Language: C#
Database: MS SQL 2005 and up

Thanks guys!

Cullen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use resources:

How does this add more complexity to the program logic?

```
try
{
   //do something with System.Net.Mail with invalid email..
}
catch (FormatException fex)
{
    throw new Exception(Resources.ErrorMsg.Invalid_Email, fex);
}
```

## Edit

In VS2008 when you create a resource, you can define if its internal or public. So assume we set it to public, in an assembly called ClassLibrary1, we can access a property like:

ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources.InvalidError

Where InvalidError is the name of the error. Again I don't think this adds any compelxity to the logic.

Comment: My solution contains multiple projects, therefore multiple assemblies.  One of ideas is to create a resource-only assembly to store the strings and then use ResourceManager to connect to the assembly and to read the strings.  It does adds to the complexity.

Comment: @Cullen Tsering: I have to agree with Josh, the designer takes care of all of this for you, and creates a nicely typed class that exposes the strings in the resource file so that all you have to do is access it like in his sample.  Your comment indicates you haven't tried out the design time support

Comment: casperOne: Can you elaborate on the design time support please?

Comment: Do you guys believe this is the best way to go?

Comment: If it's a client application yes without a doubt. If its a web application that depends for something like Error messages probally a good fit, for other things you might want to be able to update the text without deploying anything.

Comment: Josh, thanks for clarification.  My application involves desktop client, web services and web portal.  The strings that I'm talking about includes both error as well as informational messages.  Ideally, I'd like switch between languages by just a value in a configuration file.

Comment: Anybody, please feel free to jump right in.  I'd like to know the best way handle this scenario.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

.NET already supports multiple resources for multiple cultures using a naming convention:

```
 <default resource file name>.<culture>.resx
```

Essentially as Josh pointed out VS2008 creates a nice type safe wrapper to access these resources.

However the VS UI exposes the bear minimum of what you can do.

If you create a new Resource File called exactly the same as the default, however add the culture info before the resx. (NOTE: You will need to create it somewhere else then copy it into the magic Properties folder.)

Then your application will if you have applied the culture to the thread accessing the resource pull the correct string from the specific resources.

For example:

```
    // Using the default culture
    string s = Resources.Error1Msg;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-CO");

    // Using the specific culture specified as above:
    s = Resources.Error1Msg;
```

If you need to parameterize you message, use string.Format to parameterize the output.

One word of caution is try to architect your application layers in such a way that your exceptions carry a rich payload (to describe the error), instead of relying on just text.

That way your presentation layer can present the best UI experience which might utilize the payload.

HTH

Philip

Comment: Thanks Philip for the helpful comment.